# itemStateChanged() only one checkbox is affected

Tags: java, swing

I've the following code which gives textfield and two checkboxes to bold and italic text. the eventlistener is itemStateChange but it only work with the second if else statement and skipping the first one.
I have tried switching bold one with italic but then italic is working but bold is not working. So only second if else statement is working.

Code is given bellow

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CreateFrame extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

private JTextField textField;

private JCheckBox bold, itelaic;

public CreateFrame() {

setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

setTitle("JCkeckBox Test");

textField = new JTextField(30);

textField.setText("Watch the font style change");

bold = new JCheckBox("Bold");

itelaic = new JCheckBox("Italic");

add(textField);

add(bold);

add(itelaic);

bold.addItemListener(this);

itelaic.addItemListener(this);

setLayout(new FlowLayout());

setSize(100, 120);

setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

new CreateFrame();

}

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

if(bold.isSelected()) {

textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD,14));

} else {

textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN,14));

}

if(itelaic.isSelected()){

textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.ITALIC,14));

} else {

textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN,14));

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options. Either you create anonymous inner `ItemListener` like this for both `CheckBoxes`:

```
bold.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (bold.isSelected()) {
            textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 14));
        } else {
            textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        }
    }
});
```

OR you determine the source of the `ItemEvent` before you check the state:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == bold) {
        if (bold.isSelected()) {

            textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 14));

        } else {

            textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        }
    } else if (e.getSource() == itelaic) {
        if (itelaic.isSelected()) {

            textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.ITALIC, 14));

        } else {

            textField.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        }
    }
}
```

Both options work just fine